# How to simulate soft-body voucher with bow object connected?

Tags: animation, objects, soft-body

I am new to Blender and haven't worked in a 3D app in a long time.

I am animating a voucher that is floating down gently to an invisible surface. That I got to work perfectly.

The problem I have is connecting a Christmas bow to the voucher that moves with it as if it is attached.

Can you point me in the right direction of getting this to work?

Thank you in advance.

Bird's eye view:
[image: bird's eye view]

Comment: Use tree vertex parent option ... Select bow object than voucher go to edit mode select tree corner vertices and hit Ctrl+P Parent to vertices (or something like that). BTW what is the purpose to use Decimate modifier after Soft Body?

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much. To answer your other question. Decimate modifier was accidentally left on when I was playing around with options. Thank you again for your help. It is appreciated.